# Is there a "Comprehensive Solid State" book?

Tags: reference-request, solid-state-chemistry, books

We have Comprehensive Coordination Chemistry, Comprehensive Organometallics, Comprehensive Organic Synthesis and probably few other similar works that aim to do a wide review of recent works at the time of writing.

Is there a similar review book, that reviews modeling, characterization, preparation, structures and properties of crystalline, non-molecular solids, maybe as a part of a wider topic or a series on smaller subjects?

Comment: A long time ago at a university not that far away we used "The Electronic Structure And Chemistry Of Solids" by Tony Cox for the undergraduate course. It was a good book in its time but I suspect it will be a bit dated now - especially on the modelling side, this was when something with a 50MHz clock was considered a fast computer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the closest *comprehensive* analogical literature source for solid state materials to the aforementioned series like [Elsevier's *Comprehensive Coordination Chemistry II*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/referencework/9780080437484/comprehensive-coordination-chemistry-ii), [Elsevier's *Comprehensive Organic Synthesis*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/referencework/9780080523491/comprehensive-organic-synthesis) or [Wiliey's *Inorganic Syntheses*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/series/2146) would be [Springer's *Springer Series in Solid-State Sciences*](https://www.springer.com/series/682) currently consisting of 223 titles:

> The Springer Series in Solid-State Sciences consists of fundamental scientific books prepared by leading researchers in the field. They strive to communicate, in a systematic and comprehensive way, the basic principles as well as new developments in theoretical and experimental solid-sate physics.

As for the universally recommended textbooks on solid-state chemistry in general, there are the following titles issued for the past 15 years:

1. West, A. R. *Solid State Chemistry and Its Applications*, 2nd ed.; John Wiley & Sons, Inc: Chichester, West Sussex, **2014**.
2. Simon, S. H. *The Oxford Solid State Basics*, 1st ed.; Oxford University Press: Oxford, **2013**.
3. Smart, L.; Moore, E. *Solid State Chemistry: An Introduction*, 4th ed.; CRC Press: Boca Raton, FL, **2012**.
4. Tilley, R. J. D. *Understanding Solids: The Science of Materials*; J. Wiley: Chichester, West Sussex, England; Hoboken, NJ, USA, **2004**.
5. Müller, U. *Anorganische Strukturchemie*, 6., aktualisierte Aufl., unveränd. Nachdr.; Studium; Vieweg + Teubner: Wiesbaden, **2009**. (in German)
6. Dronskowski, R. Computational Chemistry of Solid State Materials: A Guide for Materials Scientists, Chemists, Physicists and Others; Wiley-VCH: Weinheim, **2005**.

Comment: Might be worth extending [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37303/4945). I'm always surprised Müller's book never was translated. However, given that he had a *"particular"* appreciation for English, it is not that surprising any more.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Good point, I added added these six titles to the solid state chemistry section.